# Elastic Search Bulk Import from JSON without ID

Tags: json, elasticsearch, import, bulk

Is there any way to import data from a JSON file into elasticSearch without having to provide ID to each document?

I have some data in a JSON file. It contains around 1000 documents but no ID has been specified for any document. Here's how the data looks like:

---

```
{"business_id": "aasd231as", "full_address": "202 McClure 15034", "hours":{}}
{"business_id": "123123444", "full_address": "1322 lure 34", "hours": {}}
{"business_id": "sd231as", "full_address": "2 McCl 5034", "hours": {}}
```

---

It does not have `{"index":{"_id":"5"}}` before any document.
Now I am trying to import the data into elasticsearch using the following command:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/newindex/newtype/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @path/file.json
```

But it throws the following error:

```
"type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason" : "Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]"
```

This is because of the absence of ID in line before each document.

Is there any way to import the data without providing `{"index":{"_id":"5"}}` before each document.
Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

How about using Logstash which is perfectly suited for this task. Just use the following config file and you're done:

Save the following config in `logstash.conf`:

```
input {
  file {
   path => "/path/to/file.json"
   start_position => "beginning"
   sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
   codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp", "path", "host" ]
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   index => "newindex"
   document_type => "newtype"
   workers => 1
 }
}
```

Then start logstash with

```
bin/logstash -f logstash.conf
```

Comment: I tried using the config in logstash but it throws this error:                         io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
The signal HUP is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform

Comment: error: io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated The signal HUP is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform

Comment: What command are you running and what version of Logstash do you have? Make sure to save the above config in a file `logstash.conf` and then run `bin/logstash -f logstash.conf`

Comment: The error got resolved. Now it says, Pipeline Main Started. Has it loaded the data? How do i access my data?

Comment: No error anymore is a good sign. Go check in your ES if you got some new data at `curl -XGET localhost:9200/newindex/newtype/_search`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. The data is imported in ES. But its not directly under the "_source". Its inside a "_message". Also, all the field names and values are enclosed between "\". How do i resolve that?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to specify `codec => "json"`. Delete your index, fix the config as in my answer above and restart logstash.

Comment: Hey. Just one last thing. I am trying to upload a 2GB data file using the same procedure. The logstash runs without errors. But the data is not showing up in the ES. Any idea?

Comment: Try to rename your JSON file and adapt the config fiel accordingly. Also do you see any errors in the elasticsearch log?

Comment: No, there are no errors in the ES log. The created index just doesnt show up in ES.

Comment: Weird, what changed since you made it worked earlier?

Comment: File size is the only change. I am trying it now on a 2GB JSON file. Is it possible that it is getting processed at the backend and will take sometime to show up in the ES indices?

Comment: You're 100% that your file contains one JSON document per line with no newlines within documents (i.e. one document is not spanning multiple lines)?

Comment: I have checked it for a first few lines and it holds true. But I can't really say that about the whole file since there are a lot of documents in it.

Comment: I'd say try a few dozens documents, then a few hundreds, etc... Hard to say what is going on.

Comment: Cool. Will try that. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes. Actually it seems to be happening because of the size of dataset. When I split it into 4 datasets and import, it works fine.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, perhaps the easier one since you are not filtering data is to use filebeat. Latest filebeat-5.0.0-alpha3 has JSON shipper. [Here](https://github.com/sahas-/elasticsearch-filebeat-json) is a sample

Comment: Will I be able to upload a 2GB datafile using filebeat?